# Opening Microsoft Word using Mono on OS X

Tags: c#, .net, mono

I'm trying to launch Microsoft Word on OS X using Mono and `System.Diagnostics.Process`, but I keep receiving an `The file does not exist` error.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("/Applications/Microsoft\\ Office\\ 2011/Microsoft\\ Word.app/Contents/MacOS/Microsoft\\ Word");
```

Just entering the path in terminal loads `Word`.

Comment: It looks like you have a space after Microsoft where perhaps there shouldn't be one? Have you tried changing it to a string literal (prepend with @ and don't escape)?

Comment: @eddie_cat I removed the space you pointed out in my post since that was a typo, but your string literal suggestion worked! Thanks!